# Reading System.in for Intellij using Console

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I need to open up the console and type in inputs for my an assignment using Intellij.
Eclipse has a way of doing this using the **`Scanner`** class and reading **`System.in`** but running the same code in IntelliJ does not work as I **can't type anything into the console.**

Is there any way to do this?
My code is as follows:

```
    public class BasicAssertions {
       @Test
       public void testAssertions(){
           System.out.println("Enter: ");
           Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
           int first = reader.nextInt();
           int second = reader.nextInt();
           String s = reader.next();
           String s2 = reader.next();
           assertTrue(first<=second);
           assertFalse(first+second >100);
           assertNotEquals(s,s2);
           assertNotNull(s2);    
       }    
   }
```

Comment: To get System.in to work in unit tests, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482844/reading-system-in-from-the-console-using-intellij-and-junit/54028823#54028823.

Answer (score 27):

Resolved. A `public static void main()` method is required for the correct console to appear, otherwise running using the default **JUnit Test configuration** will only result in a console that doesn't receive inputs.

Answer (score 10):

Just click on the console window and type, it works for me on IntelliJ 13 CE.
See the image below, I clicked in the console and wrote the text (it appears in green then, I typed enter and it shows up):

[image]

Comment: My apologies, I just found out that a main method is required for the console to appear properly. Running the code snippet i posted through a Junit test configuration (as I was doing) would produce a console that does not receive inputs. Thank you for the answer!