# Reading System.in from the Console using Intellij and JUnit

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, console

The following code works nicely when running the code through a main in Idea

```
System.in.read()
```

However the same code inside a junit method is not working

```
public void testConsoleRead()
{
  System.in.read();
}
```

Any idea how to make this work, or something similar ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? JUnit ist first of all an automation framework; so asking users to provide some information on the console ... seems a little bit weird?! Still an interesting question; but I am wondering about the requirement behind the question.

Comment: For starting a profiler from some code, so you manually change the profiler ;-)

Comment: And allowing the user to enter text that needs to be "matched" against something is better than putting up a few constants somewhere and hardcoding the choice for one run?

Comment: It's an external profiler for the Java code, Yourkit, and the test take a 'big' initialization we don't care about with a few seconds with the actual code.

Comment: Why can't you put whatever you want in a config file and read it from there? User interaction in unit testing environment seems wrong.

Comment: I could indeed as a workaround, but doesn't answer the question ;-)

Answer (score 6):

You need to start the IDE with `-Deditable.java.test.console=true` (e.g. via "Help" > "Edit Custom VM Options..."), see [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-148698#comment=27-2257633).

Comment: Make sure to restart your IDE.

Answer (score -2):

#### You need to use the Scanner class.

First import it:

```
import java.util.Scanner
```

Now to use it:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String text = scanner.next();
scanner.close();
```

There are more methods like `scanner.nextLine();` that you should look at.

*Also you might need to handle some Exceptions here but that's not difficult to figure out.*

Comment: Scanner is similar that System.in.read(), but the same problem. No way to make it work, looks as System.in is not pointing to IDEA console

Comment: That's useful info, you should mention it in your post.
---
You should figure out where System.in is being read from. It's probably being read from another View somewhere. As long as your code pauses execution you'll know that it's working.
---
But then again doing automated testing for something that requires manual input doesn't make any sense at all.