# Why Doesn't Intellij Idea Console Pause for User Input

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, kotlin, readline

I have a simple Kotlin project which uses a Gradle build file. The main function is as follows.

```
fun main(args:Array<String>){
    println("test")
    val input = readLine()
    println("You entered: $input")
}
```

The Gradle file is as follows

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'MainKt'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version"
}

run {
    standardInput = System.in
}
```

Everything works as expected when I run Gradle from the command line like so

```
gradle run -q --console plain
```

I have configured Idea to run my project as follows

[image: Project Run Configuration]

However, it seems the Idea Run console does not wait for user input at the readLine() method and simply prints

```
test
You entered: null
```

How do I fix this in Idea? (I'm running Idea on Windows)

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-133811, should be fixed in https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thank you

Comment: To get System.in to work in unit tests, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482844/reading-system-in-from-the-console-using-intellij-and-junit/54028823#54028823.